# Pi wont boot from external SSD with ecrypted LUKS container and LVM partition layout

Tags: usb, boot, init, encryption, llvm

I want to achieve a setup in which I boot from an external SSD harddrive in an USB Raid enclosure.
The root directory lies in an encrypted luks container. The boot partition is unencrypted The problem here is, that the setup seems not be configured properly, because I do not get a password prompt via serial console. Firstly, when I tried to boot from the ssd completely the green and red led were shining constantly and no boot messages were received. I was able to fix this, with setting the lba flag to the boot partition of the ssd. Now, when booting from USB the green led is not shining constantly but blinking every 2 seconds or so. Thee eeprom is configured to boot from usb and if that fails from the sd card and it is up to date.

In summary, I try to replicate these guides with some adjustments:

- https://andreashug.medium.com/raspberry-pi-4-with-encrypted-root-partition-lvm-and-remote-unlock-457e680fc8d5
- https://rr-developer.github.io/LUKS-on-Raspberry-Pi/

My method summarized was the following:

1. First, I install raspbian OS on a sdcard with elena etcher.

```
mmcblk0               179:0    0  7.3G  0 disk  
├─mmcblk0p1           179:1    0  256M  0 part  /boot
└─mmcblk0p2           179:2    0  7.1G  0 part  /
```

I have this partition arrangement afterwards.

2. System is updated and additional software is installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo rpi-eeprom-update
sudo apt-install cryptsetup cryptsetup-initram-fs lvm2 busybox dropbear dropbear-initramfs keyutils
```

3. /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/luks_hooks and /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-rebuild were created/edited and the necessary modules were added just as it was described in the guides.
4. Subsequently, the initramfs was created:

```
sudo -E CRYPTSETUP=y mkinitramfs -o /boot/initramfs.gz
```

5. Than, I clone /boot to the ssd with dd. Before the cloning, boot in unmounted. The SSD is big (8 TB), so an GPT table is necessary on the SSD and no MS-DOS scheme as on the SD-Card is possible.

```
root@raspberry:/home/pi# time dd bs=512 if=/dev/mmcblk0p1 of=/dev/sda1  status=progress
```

The checksums were identical.

3. Afterwards in a first run, I enlarged the boot partition of sda1, but I was unable to resize the filesystem with fatresize. Therefore I stick now with the original size of 256 MB.
4. I created a new partition on the ssd and here I created a luks container. I created logical volumes for root, swap and a data volume.
   I ended up with a a partition layout like this:

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0  7.1T  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    0    2G  0 part  
└─sda2                  8:2    0  7.1T  0 part  
  └─luks           254:0    0  7.1T  0 crypt 
    ├─vgrasp-swap 254:1    0   25G  0 lvm   
    ├─vgrasp-root 254:2    0  200G  0 lvm
    └─vgrasp-data 254:3    0    6T  0 lvm   
mmcblk0               179:0    0  7.3G  0 disk  
├─mmcblk0p1           179:1    0  256M  0 part  /boot
└─mmcblk0p2           179:2    0  7.1G  0 part  /
```

5. From a different machine, I cloned the unmounted root partition of the sdcard (mmcblk0p2) to the luks container vgrasp-root:

```
user@pc:~$ sudo time dd bs=512 if=/dev/mmcblk0p2 of=/dev/mapper/vgrasp-root status=progress
```

6. The filesystem on /dev/mapper/vgrasp-root was enlarged afterwards.
7. /etc/fstab, /etc/crypttab, /boot/cmdline.txt and /boot/config.txt were modified.

**/boot/config.txt:**

```
[...]
# These lines were added:
enable_uart=1
initramfs initramfs.gz followkernel
```

**/boot/cmdline.txt**

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=UUID of/dev/mapper/vgrasp-root rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles cryptdevice=UUID of sda2:luks rootdelay=2
```

**/etc/crypttab**

```
# <target name> <source device>     <key file>  <options>
luks         UUID of /dev/sda2      none    luks
```

Is it necessary to use a specific name (luks-medium) for the target name here or it is enough when its identical for the one chosen in cmdline.txt?

**/etc/fstab**

```
proc                            /proc           proc    defaults                        0       0
PARTUUID of /dev/sda    /boot           vfat    defaults                        0       2
UUID of vgrasp-root              /              ext4    defaults,noatime,data=journal   0       1
UUID of vgrasp-data              /mnt/data      ext4    defaults,noatime,data=journal   0       2
UUID of vgrasp-swap            none         swap    sw                          0       0
```

8. Subsequently I also configure dropbear to be able to access via ssh in early boot stage:

In /etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook the follwing line is introduced:

`CRYPTSETUP=y`

I paste my public ssh key without line breaks in the follwing file /etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys

I change /etc/dropbear-initramfs/config the following line to:

`DROPBEAR_OPTIONS="-sgjkc cryptroot-unlock"`

9. I chroot into the system that lies on the ssd and finally rebuild the initramfs wihtout relevant errors:

```
root@raspberrypi:/# mkinitramfs -o /boot/initramfs.gz
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8156b-2.fw for built-in driver r8152
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8156a-2.fw for built-in driver r8152
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8153c-1.fw for built-in driver r8152
root@raspberrypi:/# exit
```

Unfortunately, the booting process stops with the following messages I can see over the serial console over the GPIO connector and putty when I try to boot from the USB-port:

```
PM_RSTS: 0x00001000
RPi: BOOTLOADER release VERSION:c2f8c388 DATE: Apr 29 2021 TIME: 17:11:29 BOOTMODE: 0x00000006 part: 0 BUILD_TIMESTAMP=1619712685 0x94448536 0x00d03114 0x000a5a7d
PM_RSTS: 0x00001000
part 00000000 reset_info 00000000
uSD voltage 3.3V
Initialising SDRAM 'Micron' 32Gb x2 total-size: 64 Gbit 3200
PCI reset
PCI reset
VLI: HUB2: 0xfff00000 0x24e6 MCU: 0xfff20000 0x15218
XHCI-STOP
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
xHC ports 5 slots 32 intrs 4
Boot mode: SD (01) order f4
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000000 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000f00 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
EMMC
SD retry 1 oc 0
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000000 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
SD retry 2 oc 0
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000000 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
SDV1
SD retry 3 oc 0
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000000 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
SD CMD: 0x371a0010 (55) 0x0 0x1fff0001
Failed to open device: 'sdcard' (cmd 371a0010 status 1fff0001)
Retry SD 1
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000000 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000f00 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
EMMC
SD retry 1 oc 0
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000000 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
SD retry 2 oc 0
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000000 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
SDV1
SD retry 3 oc 0
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000000 BUS: 100000 Hz actual: 100000 HZ div: 2500 (1250) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 1080
SD CMD: 0x371a0010 (55) 0x0 0x1fff0001
Failed to open device: 'sdcard' (cmd 371a0010 status 1fff0001)
Boot mode: USB-MSD (04) order f
XHCI-STOP
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
XHCI-STOP
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
xHC ports 5 slots 32 intrs 4
USB3[2] 000002b1 connected
USB2[1] 400202e1 connected
USB2 root HUB port 1 init
DEV [01:00] 2.16 000000:01 class 9 VID 2109 PID 3431
HUB init [01:00] 2.16 000000:01
USB3[2] 00281203 connected enabled
USB3 root HUB port 2 init
DEV [02:00] 3.00 000000:02 class 0 VID 0781 PID 5581
MSD device [02:00] 3.00 000000:02 conf 0 iface 0 ep 81#1024 02#1024
MSD [02:00] 3.00 000000:02 register MSD
MSD [02:00] 3.00 000000:02 LUN 0
MSD INQUIRY [02:00] 3.00 000000:02
MSD [02:00] 3.00 000000:02 lun 0 block-count 30031250 block-size 512
MBR: 0x00002000,  524288 type: 0x0c
MBR: 0x00082000,29498770 type: 0x83
MBR: 0x00000000,       0 type: 0x00
MBR: 0x00000000,       0 type: 0x00
Trying partition: 0
lba: 8192 oem: 'mkfs.fat' volume: ' boot       '
rsc 32 fat-sectors 4033 c-count 516190 c-size 1 r-dir 2 r-sec 0
PM_RSTS: 0x00001000
Trying partition: 0
lba: 8192 oem: 'mkfs.fat' volume: ' boot       '
rsc 32 fat-sectors 4033 c-count 516190 c-size 1 r-dir 2 r-sec 0
Read config.txt bytes     2160 hnd 0x00043930 
Read start4.elf bytes  2241504 hnd 0x0000a50d 
Read fixup4.dat bytes     5411 hnd 0x0000efce 
Firmware: d9b293558b4cef6aabedcc53c178e7604de90788 Nov 18 2021 16:16:49
0x00d03114 0x00000000 0x00000fff
MEM GPU: 76 ARM: 947 TOTAL: 1023
Starting start4.elf @ 0xfeb00200 partition 0
+
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd083]
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.63-v8+ (dom@buildbot) (aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-3ubuntu1) 8.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1488 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 18 16:16:16 GMT 2021
[    0.000000] random: fast init done
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x0000000019800000, size 320 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003fffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000001ffffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003b2fffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000001ffffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000001ffffffff]
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA32: 256 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 32 pages/cpu s91416 r8192 d31464 u131072
[    0.000000] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-v2
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-v4
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM errata 1165522, 1319367, or 1530923
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 2028596
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1  smsc95xx.macaddr=xxxxxxxxxxx vc_mem.mem_base=0x3eb00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3ff00000  console=ttyS0,11522
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x0000000037300000-0x000000003b300000] (64MB)
[    0.000000] Memory: 7646508K/8244224K available (11136K kernel code, 1946K rwdata, 3984K rodata, 3712K init, 1260K bss, 270036K reserved, 327680K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 36756 entries in 144 pages
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocated 144 pages with 2 groups
[    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=4.
[    0.000000]  Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000]  Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000]  Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=4
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode
[    0.000000] irq_brcmstb_l2: registered L2 intc (/soc/interrupt-controller@7ef00100, parent irq: 10)
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x3b0/0x570 with crng_init=1
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 54.00MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0xc743ce346, max_idle_ns: 440795203123 ns
[    0.000006] sched_clock: 56 bits at 54MHz, resolution 18ns, wraps every 4398046511102ns
[    0.000242] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000307] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 108.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=216000)
[    0.000337] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000479] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.000731] Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.000826] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.002063] cgroup: Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.004320] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.005343] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.005830] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.006790] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU1
[    0.006860] CPU1: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000001 [0x410fd083]
[    0.007968] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU2
[    0.008016] CPU2: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000002 [0x410fd083]
[    0.009089] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU3
[    0.009135] CPU3: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000003 [0x410fd083]
[    0.009285] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.009328] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated.
[    0.009346] CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL0 Support
[    0.009362] CPU features: detected: CRC32 instructions
[    0.009379] CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL1 Support
[    0.042387] CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL2
[    0.042459] alternatives: patching kernel code
[    0.044344] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.054938] Enabled cp15_barrier support
[    0.054984] Enabled setend support
[    0.055186] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.055218] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.063639] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.064446] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.064810] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.067982] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
[    0.068284] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations
[    0.069201] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
[    0.069298] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.069673] audit: type=2000 audit(0.068:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.070162] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.070619] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.071035] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.071208] ASID allocator initialised with 65536 entries
[    0.071346] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.110724] bcm2835-mbox fe00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.116430] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2021-11-18T16:16:49, variant start
[    0.120441] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is d9b293558b4cef6aabedcc53c178e7604de90788
[    0.154309] bcm2835-dma fe007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.158238] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.158639] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.158848] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.158906] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.158983] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.159342] usb_phy_generic phy: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.161206] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    1.178369] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    1.178483] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.178649] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    1.178881] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    1.189441] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.190225] IP idents hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    1.196164] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    1.196245] TCP established hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    1.196641] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    1.197661] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 65536 bind 65536)
[    1.197951] UDP hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    1.198059] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    1.198454] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.199372] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    1.199392] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    1.199406] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    1.199420] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    1.199444] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    1.199694] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    2.746169] Freeing initrd memory: 21592K
[    2.748446] hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_cortex_a72 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    2.748719] kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 44 bits
[    2.749934] kvm [1]: vgic interrupt IRQ9
[    2.750216] kvm [1]: Hyp mode initialized successfully
[    2.752542] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    2.752896] workingset: timestamp_bits=46 max_order=21 bucket_order=0
[    2.759229] zbud: loaded
[    2.760953] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    2.761637] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    2.761683] Key type id_resolver registered
[    2.761698] Key type id_legacy registered
[    2.761815] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    2.761833] nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
[    2.762946] Key type asymmetric registered
[    2.762965] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    2.763017] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[    2.763273] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    2.763291] io scheduler kyber registered
[    2.767375] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: host bridge /scb/pcie@7d500000 ranges:
[    2.767408] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   No bus range found for /scb/pcie@7d500000, using [bus 00-ff]
[    2.767480] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:      MEM 0x0600000000..0x063fffffff -> 0x00c0000000
[    2.767559] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   IB MEM 0x0000000000..0x01ffffffff -> 0x0400000000
[    2.831300] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: link up, 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 (SSC)
[    2.831672] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    2.831695] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    2.831717] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x600000000-0x63fffffff] (bus address [0xc0000000-0xffffffff])
[    2.831803] pci 0000:00:00.0: [14e4:2711] type 01 class 0x060400
[    2.832035] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    2.835825] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    2.835892] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    2.836126] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    2.839576] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    2.839603] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64bit]
[    2.839643] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    2.839667] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    2.845655] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    2.846491] bcm2835-aux-uart fe215040.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    2.848741] iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    2.849121] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3eb00000 mem_size:0x3ff00000(1023 MiB)
[    2.850069] gpiomem-bcm2835 fe200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0xfe200000
[    2.850457] cacheinfo: Unable to detect cache hierarchy for CPU 0
[    2.861453] brd: module loaded
[    2.873419] loop: module loaded
[    2.875094] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    2.878330] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    2.879970] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
[    2.889239] libphy: bcmgenet MII bus: probed
[    2.949352] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
[    2.950453] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    2.950521] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    2.950578] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    2.996632] pci 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.996806] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.996842] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.997620] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000060000000890
[    2.998899] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.10
[    2.998920] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.998938] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.998953] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.10.63-v8+ xhci-hcd
[    2.998969] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    2.999643] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.999741] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    3.000354] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    3.000381] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    3.000407] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    3.000841] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.10
[    3.000860] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    3.000876] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    3.000891] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.10.63-v8+ xhci-hcd
[    3.000906] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    3.001611] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.001682] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    3.003196] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    3.004053] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    3.004151] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    3.004357] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    3.006421] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    3.009983] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    3.010002] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    3.010701] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    3.011253] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    3.015112] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    3.015482] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    3.015700] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.015717] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.016049] ashmem: initialized
[    3.023998] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    3.024051] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    3.024173] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    3.024821] registered taskstats version 1
[    3.024855] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    3.025359] Key type ._fscrypt registered
[    3.025377] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    3.025392] Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
[    3.036673] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    3.036958] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    3.037056] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 23, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    3.221576] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    3.238557] printk: console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    3.275056] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5581, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    3.397641] bcm2835-aux-uart fe215040.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    3.408177] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.421889] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    3.434583] usb 2-1: Product: Ultra
[    3.434594] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[    3.434606] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: xxxxxxxxxxx
[    7.107749] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    7.107867] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xfe215040 (irq = 24, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
[    7.157251] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    7.160503] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    7.182799] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[    7.188493] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    7.279840] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
[    7.285229] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    7.288773] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    7.295827] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    7.302808] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    7.371923] of_cfs_init
[    7.383661] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    7.388520] of_cfs_init: OK
[    7.395183] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    7.418378] mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.mmc [fe340000.mmc] using ADMA
[    8.222506] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra            1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    8.339146] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    8.344015] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 30031250 512-byte logical blocks: (15.4 GB/14.3 GiB)
[    8.348754] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    8.359927] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    8.366102] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    8.371727] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    8.379633] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    9.048843] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[    9.050330] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    9.093025]  sda: sda1 sda2
[    9.109151] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    9.140656] Freeing unused kernel memory: 3712K
[    9.165371] Run /init as init process
[    9.192073] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[   10.073493] brcmstb-i2c fef04500.i2c:  @97500hz registered in polling mode
[   10.104204] ttyAMA ttyAMA0: 5 input overrun(s)
[   10.104337] brcmstb-i2c fef09500.i2c:  @97500hz registered in polling mode
[   10.183063] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
[   10.184290] [drm] Initialized v3d 1.0.0 20180419 for fec00000.v3d on minor 0
[   10.247146] Registered IR keymap rc-cec
[   10.262892] rc rc0: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0
[   10.294890] input: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0/input0
[   10.327271] vc4_hdmi fef00700.hdmi: Could not register sound card: -517
[   10.400562] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
[   10.427405] Registered IR keymap rc-cec
[   10.450810] rc rc0: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0
[   10.485368] input: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0/input1
[   10.523696] vc4_hdmi fef00700.hdmi: Could not register sound card: -517
[   10.562258] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[   10.686363] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.43.0-ioctl (2020-10-01) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[   12.828144] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII (RX delay)
[   12.861970] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[   12.891831] ttyAMA ttyAMA0: 16 input overrun(s)
[   12.954981] random: cryptsetup: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[   16.989491] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[   17.014588] ttyAMA ttyAMA0: 4 input overrun(s)
[   18.448579] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[   18.463731] ttyAMA ttyAMA0: 2 input overrun(s)
[   18.468199] Segment Routing with IPv6
```

The interisting thing is, that on this point, I am already capable of sending a ping to raspberry and the ssh-server already seems to be responsive. Still, I can not connect to it, because I get the message that the public key is invalid. It is the key that was previously put into /etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys:

```
user@pc:~$ ping 192.168.1.3
PING 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.99 ms
[...]
^C
--- 192.168.1.3 ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 14 received, 0% packet loss, time 29ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.707/2.395/3.994/0.629 ms
```

```
user@pc:~$ ssh pi@192.168.1.3
pi@192.168.1.3: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Normally I would expect a password promt asking for the passphrase. I asume that it impossible to do this over the gpio connector and accessing the busybox shell. Or are a screen and a keyboard obligatoric for this step?

Comment: what do you see on a monitor connected to the pi itself? if yo connect a keybaord too, can you log in?

Comment: you say that `the booting process stops with the following messages` and that it is somehow unfortunate? Why is it unfortunate? Doesn't look like it's failed to boot, which makes your question title misleading

Comment: @Bravo I am currently not able to do this, because I do not have a microhdmi adapter at hand, but it is ordered and will arrive on Tuesday. My expectation was that I am able to unlock the luks container via the serial console or access the dropbear server after the boot-process. Some guides imply that this works.  I would not anticipate, that the interaction with the os is limited when no visual connection is established. Is this likely? What is the explanation for that? I chose this title, because I expected a similar behavior like when booting from an unencrypted sd with a login prompt.

Comment: @Bravo How would you confirm a successful boot?

Comment: by attaching a screen and keyboard

Comment: I'm not sure that Raspberry PI OS plays well with custom initfs.. You could probably het more traction using Ubuntu for PI..

https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/how-to-boot-with-initramfs-on-raspberry-pi-4/91063

Comment: Does not help. Videoutput is black as the serial console.

Comment: @SimonBanks I decided not to pursue further on this on raspbian basis and try ubuntu indeed. Maybe its the specific combination of this 64 bit raspbian software and my hardware version. Ubuntu 20.4 LTS is not working from USB though, but with 21.10 things seem to be more easy.